# Preenchimento obrigatório

Tags: php, html

```
<label for=""><h5><strong>Dia da Semana</strong></h5></label>
<select name="Dia">
       <option value="0">Selecione o Dia</option>
        <?php
         $servername = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8'); 

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.DiasSemana ORDER BY Dias ASC";
         $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['Dias'].'">'.$ln['Dias'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>        
    </select>
```

Quero que este campo do formulário seja obrigatório preencher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça a lógica que se estiver vazio ou não conter o dado esperado, mostre a mensagem pedindo pra preencher.

Se for html5 da pra usar

```
<input type="text" name="nome_do_campo" required>
```

Comment: Mas neste caso não é um `input`, é `<select name="Dia"></select>` e coloco isso e não obriga o preenchimento

Comment: O select também possui o atributo [required](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi esse seu código você quis dizer preenchimento obrigatório seria pelo usuário e não pelo PHP.
Então vamos entender o HTML gerado dinamicamente os options, mesmo que fossem valores estáticos.

Você pode verificar o option selecionado como `ARRAY` do SELECT usando o `selectedIndex` para identificar a opção selecionada.

Então o `Selecione o Dia` é um valor preenchido, então você precisará validar com JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function validarFormulario(){
 var myform = document.forms['formulario'] || document.formulario;
 if(myform.Dia.value == "0" || myform.Dia.selectedIndex == 0){
  alert('Preencha a data');
 }else{
  myform.submit();
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario" action="arquivo.php" method="POST">
<select name="Dia">
  <option value="0">Selecione...</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="validarFormulario()" />
</form>
```

Também pode validar com PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['method'] === "POST"){
   if($_POST['Dia'] == "" || $_POST['Dia'] == null){
      /* Não Preenchido */
   }else{
      /* Preenchido */
   }
}
```

Comment: Na primeira opção realmente aparece a mensagem, mas ao fazer ok ele insere a linha na mesma por preencher na tabela da base de dados

Comment: Foi erro meu, escrevi a IF ao contrário de como deveria funcionar, vale lembrar que deve inserir todo o método de gravação dos dados dentro do ELSE. Eu melhorei a explicação do formulário e corrigi um erro da função PHP

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja usar apenas php, recomendo assim

Depois da tag `<select>`, deverá aparecer uma mensagem de erro a dizer que está errado.

Use este código

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['botao_submit']) && $_POST['Dia'] != "")){
echo "Campo Obrigatório";
}
?>
```

Com o código acima ele iria verificar se tinha sido submetido o formulário, caso tivesse sido submetido e o campo tivesse vazio, ele iria aparecer aquele código.

Utilizar o `required` no `select` também resulta mas se alguém fosse a `Inspecionar Elemnto` poderia bem eliminar o `required` do select e enviaria em branco, com aquele código não.

Comment: E dentro do `if` coloco a consulta à base de dados?

Comment: Editei a resposta